# kotlin: convert postgres TIMESTAMP to unix date using criteria builder

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, date, datetime

Currently need to construct query that selects rows based on date, in postgres table date stored as `TIMESTAMP`, I receive query param in unix epoch time which is `Int` field, is I need to convert one to another, would love to know how to do it using `criteria builder`, since the rest of the query also constructed using `criteria builder`

any help appreciated!

trying to do something like this:

```
if (cmd.firstDate != null) {
criteria.and(Criteria.where("myDate").greaterThanOrEquals(cmd.firstDate))
}
```

and then receive results like this:

```
val query = Query.query(criteria)

val content = template.select(MyClassName::class.java)
            .matching(query).all().collectList()
```

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1682369792); 04/24/2023 13:56:32 PDT`.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code, for example how you use the "criteria builder" for the other parameters. That might help to get better answers.

Comment: @Meier added code snipper, showing what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are using the wrong data type for your column. Use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

## `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

> in postgres table date stored as TIMESTAMP, I receive query param in unix epoch time

Well, you have a problem there.

The `TIMESTAMP` type in Postgres has a full name of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)). This means a value in that column has **merely a date and a time-of-day**, but lacks the context of a time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So a value of this type **does *not* represent a moment**, is *not* a point on the timeline.

For example, if you record merely “noon on January 23, 2023”, we have no way to know if you meant noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments, each several hours apart.

In contrast a Unix epoch time represents a moment, a point on the timeline. Therefore, you are asking to compare [apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).

> I need to convert one to another

Asking that makes no sense.

## `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

The solution is to  use the correct data type. Use a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Postgres offers such a type, by the same name.

From there you can easily make comparison using Java.

If by “unix epoch time” you meant a count of whole seconds or a count of milliseconds since an [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of the first moment of 1970 as seen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then use the `Instant` class to parse that count.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( x ) ;
```

… or:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( x ) ;
```

For use in [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), use the `OffsetDateTime` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Pass to a `PreparedStatement` or your database access framework.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

By the way, Postgres uses any offset or time zone info included with an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to adjust the date and time to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) while saving the data to a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. The original zone/offset is then discarded.

Every value retrieved from a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is ***always* in UTC**, having an offset of zero. Always. Confusion on this point comes from some tools and middleware that insist on applying a default time zone to the retrieved value. I consider such well-intentioned behavior to be a lie, creating the illusion of a time zone having been stored when in fact all values in that column are in UTC (offset of zero).

Comment: thanks a lot for the extensive answer, sadly I cannot change the datatype in the database I currently use, maybe you know how I can compare seconds since an epoch reference and timestamp using something close to an example I just added to the question?